# Help! Rabbit has a circular bald spot. It's very red and has hardened

Tags: health, rabbits, grooming, skin-condition

[image: the spot is circular and about 1 inch in diameter]

I was busy a couple days ago and and when I checked on him I found this. Is this from stress? Is this a wound from over grooming? The spot is dry, hard and red. It's circular and very distinct from the skin nearby. The rest of his skin is normal. Behavior wise he is very happy, binkying around like usual. He eats normally. His droppings are solid. Does anyone know what's wrong? I want to take him to the vet but I don't know any rabbit savvy vet in my city, since rabbits are a very uncommon pet in my country.

Comment: Where on the rabbit is the spot?  You said he is doing binkys so presumably has some run time in the house, how much time does he spend in a cage?  Can you post a new question about how to find a good rabbit vet? We don't have that question and we need it.